# When posting to a URL, Google Analytic's Event isn't firing

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, google-analytics, cron

I am using a Cron-Job to search the database I have every 15 minutes for new users, the problem I am running into though, is when it finds any new users, it is supposed to use jQuery's GET function to get another URL with some parameters, for instance:

```
http://sampleurl.com/report_to_ga.php?username=TestUser&register_date=2013-07-01&account_type=Facebook&gaid=UA-XXXXXX-1
```

When I post to that url, it is supposed to firing a Google Analytic's Event ON that page (not the page I am sending it from) to register that person as a new user in Google Analytics.

So basically, in a shorter way of saying it, I have two pages.

Page A - Cron-Job start page, searches database for new user accounts, then posts to Page B.

Page B - Gets data from URL and is supposed to firing a Google Analytics Event based on that.

For whatever reason though, the events aren't firing. Why would this be?  The code works if I hit the page directly.

Comment: cron= command line= no browser therefore no javascript

Comment: Really? Wow, okay, is there any way to get this to work?

Comment: don't use client side scripting when there is no *client*

Comment: One possibility to get this to work, is forge the analytics requests yourself. Google has an API for that, but it uses Javascript as well. You could try `node.js` to run that script on the server. But maybe you should describe your use case a little more. Google Analytics is for reporting page views, not for reporting just anything by faking page requests, so I'm wondering what you're trying to accomplish

Comment: @GolezTrol One example of why you would want to do this is to record ecommerce transaction refunds in Google Analytics, where no client pageview is actually triggered, but you still want to record a negative transaction to void the initial transaction.

Answer (score 1):

If you're tracking via `ga.js`, you can use [php-ga](https://code.google.com/p/php-ga/) to send tracking data to the Google servers from your server -- it's essentially *ga.js in PHP*.

If you're using the newer Universal Analytics (`analytics.js`), you can use [Google Analytics Measurement Protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/) to send data.